# Why a linux redirect truncates the file?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I have a file called "test.txt" like that:

```
hello world
```

it is, just a 'hello world' string. If I use a perl regex:

```
perl -pe "s/hello/bye/g" test.txt
```

it says:

```
bye world
```

but if I try to redirect that file to itself:

```
perl -pe "s/hello/bye/g" test.txt > test.txt
```

the resulting file is empty. Why? And how can I 'filter' a regex over a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`perl` accepts the parameter `-i` for inplace. With this, you can process a file with a perl program and immediately have it written back.

Comment: @Ivan The argument to `-i` is only the extension for backup, so you can omit it or take something simple, such as `~` or `.bak`.

Answer (score 3):

It opens the file for writing due to the redirect before the application gets a chance to read from it. Redirect to a temporary file instead, then rename it after.

Comment: To clarify, one of the effects of opening the file for writing is that the file is truncated (its size is changed to have length zero) so it is empty by the time the application opens it.

Answer (score 2):

The redirection takes place while your shell is parsing your command line. This happens before the actual command is executed, thus the file you redirect to is overwritten before you have the chance to read it.